# How to remove an entry from nautilus context menu?

Tags: nautilus, menu

I'd like to remove a specific menu entry on the nautilus right-click context menu - the "arrange alphabetically" option - since, being right after the "paste" entry, an imprecise click might produce a very disappointing mess among icons all over my desktop... as just happened once again minutes ago.

Is it possible to edit nautilus context-menu entries somehow?
Thanks everyone